# What does "overall" mean in "overall proportion"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read the entire article and still don't know what "overall" means. Does the survey have the response options like "unhappy" and "very unhappy" and they combined the percentages in different response options and this is an overall proportion. I don't know how the definition "in general" fits in this sentence?

> The **overall proportion** of those surveyed who were not happy with their
> looks rose to 33% this year, from 29% last year and 26% two years ago.
> -- [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2013/nov/29/girls-low-self-esteem-rising-girlguiding-report)

Comment: Please edit to show that you understand the words "overall" and "proportion," and that you're just puzzled by the sentence's wording. (Hehe, I started to say "overall" wording)

Comment: overall here means total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article does a bad job of establishing its context, probably because it is not directly reporting the data but reporting *on* a report which presumably labeled them better. Yes, "overall" would imply that some subcategories are being combined. You could expand it into "Over all of those surveyed, the proportion who were not happy...."

Reading on in the article, many other statistics are broken down by age group, e.g.

> Although most across the surveyed group report being happy most of the time, 24% of the 16- to 18-year-olds say they are not very or at all happy, far more than last year's 14%.

... and that seems the most likely here.